# Is asking the same question once in C#, then once in VB, considered duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

Day 1:

- Apr 20 '11, [compiling assembly from the other just compiled assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729403/compiling-assembly-from-the-other-just-compiled-assembly) is asked in C#
- Apr 20 '11, it's answered with replace `assemblyDomain.DoCallBack(assamblykub);` with `assamblykub()`

Day 2:

- Apr 21 '11, [compiling assembly from the other just compiled assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741007/compiling-assembly-from-the-other-just-compiled-assembly) is asked in VB.NET
- Apr 21 '11, it's answered with replace `assemblyDomain.DoCallBack(AddressOf assamblykub)` with `assamblykub`

So, from first question, the OP already knew the essence of what was wrong and how to solve it, yet he asked it again in a different programming language. Is that acceptable, or should I vote to close as duplicate?

---

Note: we could have the same discussion if a question was asked once in Swift, then once in Objective-C.

Comment: I would argue that it's not a duplicate because someone searching for that issue (and searching specifically for VB or C# exclusively) may not find the answer. Alternatively, the SO question may turn up in their searches, but because the language for which the question was answered is different to the one they're searching for, it might be overlooked.

Comment: The OP just made a very common mistake.  He hoped that asking this in [c#] would get him a better answer and that a language converter was going to help him get the right code.  Didn't work, converters notoriously get this kind of code wrong.  Certainly the most basic reason why it is not a dup.

Comment: From a more general point of view, Dupe is more related to the answer than the question. If one of the answer give is in both language and valid well it's a dupe. Cross language duplicate(as I call them) are not dupe if an answer doesnt specify the difference and similarity of the answer in target lang.

Comment: In this case, in the Vb question, Op state in comment that it's not the answer but still find it usefull enought to accept it. So even if the accepted answer is the same on both, I'm not sure either of them is the complete correct answer.

Comment: For vb.net/c#, I'd argue they are dupes. They both use the exact same framework, and the syntax of both languages are clear enough that unless it is logically complex or uses language specific features (like vb's include xml) then they're duplicates.